# For a given period, getting the smallest list of dates, using jokers

Tags: code-golf, date

Consider a date formatted in `YYYY-MM-DD`.
You can use the joker `*` at the end of the date string. E.g. `2016-07-2*` describes all the dates from `2016-07-20` to `2016-07-29`.

Now, consider a period represented by a start date and an end date.

The algorithm must find the smallest possible list of dates representing the period.

Let's use an exemple. For the following period:

- start date: `2014-11-29`
- end date: `2016-10-13`

The algorithm must return an array containing the following list of dates:

- `2014-11-29`
- `2014-11-30`
- `2014-12-*`
- `2015-*`
- `2016-0*`
- `2016-10-0*`
- `2016-10-10`
- `2016-10-11`
- `2016-10-12`
- `2016-10-13`

Comment: The winning objective(s) are ambiguous. I suggest changing it to codegolf (i.e. solve the task in the fewest bytes possible) and always require answers to output the smallest list of dates.

Comment: Maybe it's simply not the best site for this, it is more a question (i.e. "I can't find this algorithm in Ruby on Rails") than a challenge "for fun". I'm rather new here...

Comment: I suggest you try [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) and then ask it as a question rather than a challenge. If rephrased, the challenge is still interesting in my opinion and deserves a chance (as code golf).

Comment: Yeah, I think finding the algorithm is still fun and challenging, but I was not interested in the code-golf side... Well I rephrased it, changed the tags, and now I'm gonna ask stackoverflow while still following this post. Thanks!

Comment: Follow-up: I posted on Stackoverflow yesterday, but today I had a working code in Ruby (it doesn't "jokerize" months, but almost there): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40506639/for-a-given-period-getting-the-smallest-list-of-dates-using-jokers

Comment: In your example, could we also return `2014-11-3*` instead of `2014-11-30`?

Comment: Yep, of course.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>541</s> 343 bytes

I wanted to get the algorithm working in the first place; but golfing it down was actually far more fun than I expected (especially browsing the [supported date & time formats](http://php.net/manual/datetime.formats.php)).

Three major actions saved about 130 bytes; but the 70 bytes from minor golfings
(which also rendered one of the large steps obsolete) carried a lot of fun.

```php
for($a=($f=strtotime)($argv[1]);!$p=$a>$z=$f($argv[2]);$a+=86400){$x=$z<$e=$f(Dec31,$a);(101<$q=date(md,$a))?$q-1001|$x?:$a=$e+$p="1*":($x?($t=$f(IX30,$a))>$z?:$a=$t+$p="0*":$a=$e+$p="*");$p?:($q%100>1|$z<($t=$f(date(Ymt,$a)))?$q%10>0&$q%100>1|$z<($t=min($t,$a+777600))?:$a=$t+$p="m-$q[2]*":$a=$t+$p="m-*");echo date("Y-".($p?:"m-d"),$a),"
";}
```

takes input from command line arguments. Run with `-nr`or [test it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ecf460593269939f8c1e1a45ace3116b88ffa6da).

**notes**

- prints `Y-m-3*` for `Y-m-30`; add 7 bytes to fix: Insert `|$a==$t` after `777600))`.
- throws warnings in PHP 7.1; add 5 bytes to fix: Replace `+$p` with `+!$p`.
- A breakdown and some golfings explained are ready to be posted;
  but I´ll wait a bit to see if someone else submits before I spoil.